# Ajax File Upload Questions

Tags: ajax, file, upload

If i am using ajax to upload a file and when the file i uploading , I traverse to some other page, will the file upload continue or will be aborted?

Regards
Manjit

Comment: did you try this yourself? shouldn't be too hard to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file upload will be aported. You'd have to load content with Ajax too instead of traversing to another page.